# How to handle extjs treegrid selection event?

Tags: extjs4, treegrid

I have a simple extjs treegrid, and I want to show something based on row selection, how can I add this listener into my treegrid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use listener for grid's [`select`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-select) event.

```js
   Ext.create('KitchenSink.view.tree.TreeGrid', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        listeners: {
            select: function(selModel, record, index, eOpts) {
                console.debug(record.get('user'));
            }
        }
   });
```

**Fiddle with live example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/6t7**

Comment: Thanks,great!This exactly what I want.